# Why can't I set a default ruby with chruby in my .zprofile

Tags: ruby, zsh, chruby

After upgrading to Yosemite my ruby dev environment was not working well so I thought I would take the opportunity to switch to chruby from rbenv.

It's all gone pretty well after installing and I can switch between rubies easily, but I cannot set a default Ruby.

If I add the line `chruby ruby-2.1.3` to my `~/.zprofile` file then open a new terminal window I get the following error message;

```
/Users/brad/.zprofile:1: command not found: chruby
```

I have added `source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh` to my `~/.zshrc` file as described in the configuration section for chruby. I'm not sure what else to do to get this working - I'm no expert at finding my way around shell config settings. Any clever ideas?

Comment: `.zprofile` is sourced before `.zshrc`

Comment: OK, so why is the recommended way to set a default Ruby the way I have done it then? It feels like I've missed a step, but I don't know what.

Comment: Recommended where and by whom? It may just be, that the author of the recommendation never really tested it with `zsh`.

Comment: In the chruby readme by the chruby author.

Comment: Maybe the documentation is incorrect or assumes a specific setup. Have you tried to source `chruby.rb` from within `.zprofile` before calling `chruby`?